# display a date on an edit from from mongo using ejs

Tags: mongodb, date, ejs

There is an edit page where a user can, obviously, edit aspects of an event. Everything displays fine except the Date shows empty.

I am using the `type="date"` in my html which may be a cause, how can I get around this so that I can show the date, because when it saves it saves as null after editing the event

View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="editEvent[startDate]" placeholder="Date" value="<%= event.startDate %>">
 </div>
```

Route:

```
router.get("/event/:id/edit", isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
Event.findById(req.params.id, function (err, foundEvent) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        console.log("Cannot find the event...maybe the database isnt running?")
    } else {
        res.render("eventEdit", {event: foundEvent});
```

Everything works fine but the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out its an HTML thing, if you want to display a date you have to have it formattted as `YYYY-MM-DD` then it shows fine, otherwise it doenst recognize the format.

This comes into account if you use the `type="date"` attribute in your input

I had to edit the event date coming from mongo using momentjs and here is the line I used.

`var newDate = moment(foundEvent.startDate).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
            res.render("eventEdit", {event: foundEvent, newDate:newDate});`

The `newDate` is the variable being passed to the template, then I just have:

```
 <input class="form-control" type="date" name="editEvent[startDate]" placeholder="Date" value="<%= newDate %>">
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add some more information to the question? at the moment it looks quite unclear. like how is your server set up.

Comment: I added the Route to the question, what else do you need?

Comment: I'll say set up your mongo schema to take have 

`startDate: Date`

Then check to make sure the startDate in the database isn't null. Also to further diagnose the problem try and split foundEvent up in the route. Like just add eDate: foundEvent.startDate. ..... are you able to see the contents of startDate initially? .. I'll like to see the function you call for saving the file