# Mongoose date value to export to edit form

Tags: node.js, mongodb, forms, mongoose, ejs

i have a data model as per below:

```
var SiteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   DateFrom: Date,
   DateTo: Date,
});
```

How import these values to my edit form?
I tried the below:

```
Start Date: <input class="form-control" type="date" name="formValue[DateFrom]" value="<%= varReturnValue.DateFrom %>">
End Date: <input class="form-control" type="date" name="formValue[DateTo]" value="<%= varReturnValue.DateTo %>">
```

Screenshot of the result here:
[form result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaIZR.jpg)

On mongo, i am getting the below value:

```
DateFrom: 2017-12-01T00:00:00.000Z,
DateTo: 2018-10-26T00:00:00.000Z,
```

Comment: duplicate question [display-a-date-on-an-edit-from-from-mongo-using-ejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942473/display-a-date-on-an-edit-from-from-mongo-using-ejs)

Comment: thanks for the info. but i was avoiding using moment as i can only use certain npm packages for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML date type input does not support ISO date format as value. It should be in "YYYY-MM-DD" format for the input to display.

In your code where you receive your data use this snippet:

```
varReturnValue.DateFrom = convertToYYYYMMDD(varReturnValue.DateFrom);
varReturnValue.DateTo = convertToYYYYMMDD(varReturnValue.DateTo);

function convertToYYYYMMDD(d) {
    date = new Date(d);
    year = date.getFullYear();
    month = date.getMonth()+1;
    dt = date.getDate();

    if (dt < 10) {
        dt = '0' + dt;
    }
    if (month < 10) {
        month = '0' + month;
    }
    return (year+'-' + month + '-'+dt);
}
```